# Getting constant error on Spyder, please advise

Tags: python, spyder

This is the error I am getting:

```
invalid command name "1771926755840move"
    while executing
    "1771926755840move"
    ("after" script)
    invalid command name "1771922102464move"
    while executing
    "1771922102464move"
    ("after" script)
    invalid command name "1771947147520move"
    while executing
    "1771947147520move"
    ("after" script)
    Tcl_AsyncDelete: async handler deleted by the wrong thread
```

Below is my code:

```
from turtle import *
from random import *
from freegames import vector
from playsound import playsound
import winsound
from tkinter import *
from timeit import default_timer as timer
from datetime import timedelta
from threading import Event
"""
def paused():
    Event.wait()
def unpaused():
    Event.release()
"""    
root = Tk()
root.title("OPTIONS")

def stop():
    bye()
    winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_PURGE)
def gamingarea():
    bird = vector(0, 0)
    balls = []
    winsound.PlaySound('C:/Users/SONY/Desktop/cs.wav', winsound.SND_LOOP + winsound.SND_ASYNC)
    start = timer()
    def tap(x, y):
         lift = vector(0, 30)
         bird.move(lift)
    def inside(point):
        return -200 < point.x < 200 and -200 < point.y < 200
    
    def draw(alive):
        clear()
        goto(bird.x, bird.y)
        if alive:
            dot(20, "green")
        else: 
            dot(20, "red")
            winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_PURGE)#when bird is red, music stops
            end = timer()
            color("orange")
            write(str(timedelta(seconds=end-start)), align = "center", font=("Comic Sans MS", 20, "normal", "bold"))
        for ball in balls:
            goto(ball.x, ball.y)
            dot(20, "black")
        update()
    def move():
        bird.y -= 5
        for ball in balls:
            ball.x -= 3 
        if randrange(10) == 0:
            y = randrange(-199, 199)
            ball = vector(199, y)
            balls.append(ball)
        while len(balls) > 0 and not inside(balls[0]):
            balls.pop(0)
        if not inside(bird):
            draw(False)
            return 
        for ball in balls:
            if abs(ball - bird) < 15: 
                draw(False)
                return 
        draw(True)
        ontimer(move, 50)
    title("Dodgy Ball")
    setup(420, 420)
    hideturtle()#turtle is hidden
    up() 
    tracer(False)#Used to turn off animations. When false, animations are turned off. It also turns off automatic updates
    onscreenclick(tap)#calling the tap function when touchpad is touched
    move()
    bgcolor("blue")
    done()
startbutton = Button(root, text = "START", padx=100,pady=100, command=gamingarea)
endbutton = Button(root, text = "KILL!", padx=100,pady=100, command=stop)
#pausebutton = Button(root, text = "PAUSE!", padx = 100, pady = 100, command=paused)
#unpausebutton = Button(root, text = "UNPAUSE", padx = 100, pady = 100, command = unpaused)
startbutton.pack()
endbutton.pack()
#pausebutton.pack()
#unpausebutton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

PS: It's a game I am designing with my friend

Thanks

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: is this correct indetanions? Why do you create function inside `gamingarea()` ?

Comment: is this really starting? I can't move bird - and problem can be `done()` which finish `turtle` before even game starts. Better don't use `import *` because now I don't know if `move()` is from module `turtle` or `tkinter` or maybe from your code - so code is unreadable.

Comment: better reduce code in question - we can't use it without `.wav` - but don't add .wav to question. Better remove `PlaySound` from code in question.

Comment: my first idea was: `ontimer` uses `tkinter.after` to run again `move` (and this gives message `("after" script)` ) and it tries to move objects but they were deleted/removed and it can't move them (and this gives messages `invalid command name "1771926755840move"`, etc.) I saw similar problem with `after` in `tkinter` and `turtle` is built on top of `tkinter`. Maybe when you do `bye` it deletes objects but it doesn't stop `ontimer` which still want to draw object. You may need `if running: ontimer(50, move)` in `move` and before `bye` you need `running = False` to stop loop in `move`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is only when game is running (bird is alive) and you try to kill game.

Whey you press `kill it` then it runs `turtle.bye()` which deletes all objects and it removes window but it doesn't stop `ontimer()` which still want to run `move()` and draw objects (but they don't exists any more and this gives message `invalid command name "1771926755840move"`).

When you press `kill it` then it should set variable ie. `running = False`

```
def stop():
    global running    
    
    running = False
```

which should be checked in `move` to stop loop and close window

```
    if running:
        # repeate loop and run `move` again
        turtle.ontimer(move, 50)
    else:
        # stop loop and close window
        turtle.bye()
        #winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_PURGE)
```

---

My version with reduced modules.

I create own class `vector` so I don't need `freegames` which I don't know.

I use `datetime` instead of `timeit` because then `end-start` gives me directly `timedelta`.

I commented `winsound` because it works only with `Windows` but I uses `Linux`.

I added code for `paused`, `unpased` and it doesn't need `Threading`.

```
#from turtle import *   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
#from random import *   # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
#from tkinter import *  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

import turtle
import tkinter as tk
import random
import datetime
#import winsound

# --- classes ---

class vector():

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        
    def move(self, other):
        self.x += other.x
        self.y += other.y 
               
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return vector(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y)
                
    def __abs__(self):
        return (self.x**2 + self.y**2)**0.5
        
# --- functions ---

def paused():
    global pause
    
    pause = True

def unpaused():
    global pause
    
    pause = False

def stop():
    global running    
    
    if running:
        # stop loop `ontimer(move, 50)`
        running = False
    else:
        # exit when bird is dead
        turtle.bye()
        #winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_PURGE)
                
def gamingarea():
    global running
    global pause
        
    running = True
    pause   = False

    bird = vector(0, 0)
    balls = []
    #winsound.PlaySound('C:/Users/SONY/Desktop/cs.wav', winsound.SND_LOOP + winsound.SND_ASYNC)
    start = datetime.datetime.now()

    def tap(x, y):
        lift = vector(0, 30)
        bird.move(lift)

    def inside(point):
        return -200 < point.x < 200 and -200 < point.y < 200

    def draw(alive):
        global running
        
        turtle.clear()
        turtle.goto(bird.x, bird.y)
        
        if alive:
            turtle.dot(20, "green")
        else: 
            turtle.dot(20, "red")
            #winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_PURGE)#when bird is red, music stops
            turtle.color("orange")
            end = datetime.datetime.now()
            diff = end-start
            turtle.write(str(diff.seconds), align = "center", font=("Comic Sans MS", 20, "normal", "bold"))
            running = False
            
        for ball in balls:
            turtle.goto(ball.x, ball.y)
            turtle.dot(20, "black")
            
        turtle.update()

    def move():
        if not pause:
            bird.y -= 5
            
            for ball in balls:
                ball.x -= 3 
                
            if random.randrange(10) == 0:
                y = random.randrange(-199, 199)
                ball = vector(199, y)
                balls.append(ball)
                
            while len(balls) > 0 and not inside(balls[0]):
                balls.pop(0)
                
            if not inside(bird):
                draw(False)
                return 
                
            for ball in balls:
                if abs(ball - bird) < 15: 
                    draw(False)
                    return 
                    
            draw(True)

        if running:
            # repeate loop `ontimer(move, 50)`
            turtle.ontimer(move, 50)
        else:
            # stop loop `ontimer(move, 50)` and exit
            turtle.bye()
            #winsound.PlaySound(None, winsound.SND_PURGE)
                   
    turtle.title("Dodgy Ball")
    turtle.setup(420, 420)
    turtle.hideturtle()  # turtle is hidden
    turtle.up() 
    turtle.tracer(False)  # Used to turn off animations. When false, animations are turned off. It also turns off automatic updates
    turtle.onscreenclick(tap)  # calling the tap function when touchpad is touched
    move()
    turtle.bgcolor("blue")
    turtle.done()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("OPTIONS")

start_button = tk.Button(root, text="START", padx=100,pady=100, command=gamingarea)
end_button = tk.Button(root, text="KILL!", padx=100,pady=100, command=stop)
pause_button = tk.Button(root, text="PAUSE!", padx=100, pady=100, command=paused)
unpause_button = tk.Button(root, text="UNPAUSE", padx=100, pady=100, command=unpaused)

start_button.pack(fill='both')
end_button.pack(fill='both')
pause_button.pack(fill='both')
unpause_button.pack(fill='both')

root.mainloop()
```

---

Frankly, if you use `tkinter to display buttons then you could use` tkinter.Canvas`to draw objects, and`tkinter.bind()`to run`tap`, and` root.after()`instead of`ontimer()`to run loop - and then you don't need`turtle`