# Design Pause and Unpause function in Python Turtle

Tags: turtle-graphics

I have been trying to design pause and unpause function in python turtle with True/False, sleep, os system, but nothing works. Crashes my system badly. Any ideas on how to combat this issue?? I want it to pause the game untill I press the unpause button

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To better understand how to write a good question and get relevant answers, please read [Welcome Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) articles.

Comment: It looks like you need to use an event-driven approach.

Comment: In order to get help, you need to post your code, explain what exact steps you took and the errors you got.

Comment: I am unable to paste it for some reason, I did another question which has my code. Sorry for the hassle :( Here's the link to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66136529/getting-constant-error-on-spyder-please-advise/66142786#66142786